# Swapping between layers in leaflet heat map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to swap between layers in leaflet dynamically. So i think hide layers. Here is my code

```
    <div id="map"></div> 
    <div>
        <button  onclick='fun1()'>yellowhide</button> 
        <button  onclick='fun2()'>redhide</button> 
    </div>   

    <script> 
    //same lat long means overlapping
    addressPoints1= [     [-37.8210922667, 175.2209316333, "2"],     [-37.8210819833, 175.2213903167, "3"],     [-37.8210881833, 175.2215004833, "3"],     [-37.8211946833, 175.2213655333, "1"]]      addressPoints2= [     [-37.8210922667, 175.2209316333, "2"],     [-37.8210819833, 175.2213903167, "3"],     [-37.8210881833, 175.2215004833, "3"],     [-37.8211946833, 175.2213655333, "1"]]       
    var tiles=L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {      attribution: '',        id: 'examples.map-20v6611k'     })   var map = L.map('map', {       center: [-37.87, 175.475],      zoom: 16,       layers: [tiles]     });     var heat1 = L.heatLayer(addressPoints1,{        gradient: {1:"red"}         }).addTo(map); var heat2 = L.heatLayer(addressPoints2,{     gradient: {1:"yellow"}  }).addTo(map);      



    function fun1(){ console.log("hide yellow layer");
      $('.heat2').hide(); } function fun2(){ console.log("hide red layer");
      $('.heat1').hide();   
    }
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use jQuery and query for those layers because you've already declared before as variables `heat1` and `heat2`. You can use those to remove them from the map or add them again. At the moment you're using the `addTo` method of the layer to add the layer to the map:

```
var heat1 = L.heatLayer().addTo(map);
```

Which in the background executes the `addLayer` method of the map instance:

```
map.addLayer(heat1);
```

The map instance also has `removeLayer` method for removing layers from the map:

```
map.removeLayer(heat1);
```

So you can use that in your onclick handler:

```
function fun1 () {
    map.removeLayer(heat1);
}
```

Here's the reference with all the layer methods of L.Map: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-stuff-methods

Comment: i do not want adding or removing layer. just swapping between the layers.. like we have two button 1 for red layer and 2nd for yellow layer... when i click red button, red layer shown on top of yellow layer.and when i click yellow button, yellow layer shown on top of red layer..

Comment: In your question, you said "hide", which means "put or keep out of sight; conceal from the view". You should have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: @ iH8 yes,u r right (sort of).. but the difference between hide () and remove() is:--
hide() sets the matched elements' CSS display property to none.

remove() removes the matched elements from the DOM completely.

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't find a solution for this, have a look into the [Leaflet Layer Controls](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#control-layers).

With the controls, you can change the visible layers of a map.

```
var baseLayers = {
    "Mapbox": tiles
};

var overlays = {
    "Fancy Heatmap": heat1,
    "Another fancy Heatmap": heat2
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

HTH,
Meykel